# CATransformLayer - CAReplicatorLayer - True 3D replications

Tags: 3d, core-animation, catransformlayer, careplicatorlayer

Is it possible to get real 3D replications with the CAReplicatorLayer?

Right now I've set a replication angle of 30 degrees on the x, y and z-axis and 10 replications.

My CAReplicatorLayer is the child of a CATransformLayer which I rotated to get a view from the top side (isometric). Unfortunately the result is that I see a plane CAReplicatorLayer "floainting" in my 3D world which renders it's 3D content into a 2D plane.

Is it possible to have this to be real 3D?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [-[preservesDepth]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAReplicatorLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAReplicatorLayer/preservesDepth) property is what you are looking for.

Comment: But I didn't touch that one, and the default is NO, so shouldn't it already work? Have you been able to get non-flattened 3D replications?

Comment: I think you want to set `preservesDepth` to YES.

Comment: I tried both now and it doesn't work. It's still all flattened into one flat layer. Have you seen it working / have a working sample?